# Vertical accordion menu heading/content overflow issue

Tags: html, css, menu, accordion

I am trying to create a form inside a vertical menu, but the content and headings keep messing up. I want the opposite arrows to be on vertically left-centered (close to the two input fields) inside col-md-1.

[**JSFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/ishq786/7quyqmm6/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-lg-12" id="routeColumn">
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#collapseTwo">
                    <a class="accordion-toggle">Plan a Trip</a>
                </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="list-group">
          <div class="col-md-11">
            <span class="label label-info" style="display:block; margin-top: 5px;">ORIGIN</span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Origin">
            <span class="label label-info" style="display:block; margin-top: 5px;">DESTINATION</span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Destination">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-1">
            <span style="font-size:1.5em;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort"></span>
          </div>
          <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="optradio">Leave Now
          </label>
          <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="optradio">Leave By
          </label>
          <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="optradio">Arrive By
          </label>
          <div class="pull-right">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Get Directions</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#collapseThree">
                    <a class="accordion-toggle">Next Departures</a>
                </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="list-group">
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
            <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">List group item heading</h4>
            <p class="list-group-item-text">Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit.</p>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```